# Analytic definite integration of $\frac{(c_1e^{-ax}-c_2e^{-bx})\sin(kx)}{x^2}$

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, trigonometric-integrals

for the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\!\left(k\, x\right)\, \left(\mathrm{e}^{- a\, x} - \mathrm{e}^{- b\, x}\right)}{x^2} \,dx$$
The following analytic solution can be obtained: 
$$\frac{k\, \mathrm{log}\!\left(b^2 + k^2\right)}{2} - \frac{k\, \mathrm{log}\!\left(a^2 + k^2\right)}{2} - a\, \mathop{\mathrm{arccot}}\nolimits\!\left(\frac{a}{k}\right) + b\, \mathop{\mathrm{arccot}}\nolimits\!\left(\frac{b}{k}\right)
$$

I was wondering how we can obtain the solution for the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\!\left(k\, x\right)\, \left(C\, \mathrm{e}^{- a\, x} - D\, \mathrm{e}^{- b\, x}\right)}{x^2} \,d x
$$
Where C and D are constants.
My question can be extended for higher x powers. for example for the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\!\left(k\, x\right)\, \left(\mathrm{e}^{- a\, x} - \mathrm{e}^{- b\, x}\right)}{x^4} \,d x
$$
The analytical solution is:
$$\frac{b^3\, \mathop{\mathrm{arccot}}\nolimits\!\left(\frac{b}{k}\right)}{6} - \frac{a^3\, \mathop{\mathrm{arccot}}\nolimits\!\left(\frac{a}{k}\right)}{6} + \frac{k^3\, \mathrm{log}\!\left(a^2 + k^2\right)}{12} - \frac{k^3\, \mathrm{log}\!\left(b^2 + k^2\right)}{12} + \frac{5\, a^2\, k}{12} - \frac{5\, b^2\, k}{12} - \frac{a\, k^2\, \arctan\!\left(\frac{a}{k}\right)}{2} + \frac{b\, k^2\, \arctan\!\left(\frac{b}{k}\right)}{2} - \frac{a^2\, k\, \mathrm{log}\!\left(a^2 + k^2\right)}{4} + \frac{b^2\, k\, \mathrm{log}\!\left(b^2 + k^2\right)}{4}
$$

How can we solve the integral, if we multiply each term by different constants(C and D), as we did for the first case?

Thanks,

Comment: Some of those integrals won't converge near $0$, i.e. if $C\ne D$. The $x^4$ one will also not converge

Comment: Only the *first* integral converges (for $C\ne D$).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. You are right.

Comment: Once you "restore" the convergence, you have to evaluate something like $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\left(kx\right) \over x}\,{\expo{-px} - \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 2}\left(-1\right)^{j}p^{j}x^{j}/j! \over x^{n - 1}}$

Comment: Could you please tell me how to  "restore" the convergence and also edit the provided equation?